# Spring Cloud Kafka Stream: Publishing to DLQ is failing with Avro

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm unable to publish to Dlq topic while using ErrorHandlingDeserializer for handling the errors with combination of Avro. Below is the error while publishing.

> Topic TOPIC_DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
> ERROR KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='TOPIC', partitions=6, dlqName='TOPIC_DLT'}.container-0-C-1 o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler:250 - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@49abe531]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: failed, failedMessage=GenericMessage

And here is the application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          destination: TOPIC
          group: groupID
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers:
            - xxx:9092
          configuration:
            security.protocol: SASL_SSL
            sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
          jaas:
            loginModule: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
            options:
              username: username
              password: pwd
          consumer-properties:
            key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
            spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
          producer-properties:
            key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer            
        bindings:
          process-in-0:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
                schema.registry.url: registryUrl
                schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info: user:pwd
                security.protocol: SASL_SSL
                sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
              max-attempts: 1
              dlqProducerProperties:
                configuration:
                  basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
                  schema.registry.url: registryUrl
                  schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info: user:pwd
                key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
                value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
              deserializationExceptionHandler: sendToDlq
              ackEachRecord: true
              enableDlq: true
              dlqName: TOPIC_DLT
              autoCommitOnError: true
              autoCommitOffset: true
```

I'm using the following dependencies:

> spring-cloud-dependencies - 2021.0.1
> spring-boot-starter-parent - 2.6.3
> spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka
> kafka-schema-registry-client - 5.3.0
> kafka-avro-serializer - 5.3.0

Im not sure what exactly im missing.

Comment: The error seems to be saying the topic does not exist or that you are not authorized to view/write to it

Comment: Hmm. "topic not present" shouldn't have anything to do with the serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a lot of documentation, I found out that for spring to do the job of posting DLQ, we need to have the same number of partitions for both Original topic and DLT Topic. And if it can't be done then we need to set dlqPartitions to 1 or manually provide the DlqPartitionFunction bean. By providing dlqPartitions: 1 all the messages will go to partition 0.